# How to sort html table after changing it with javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am using an open source javascript table sorting function on my html table, but it only works if I don't alter the table with another javascript function (which I need to do).

My table:

```
<table id="myTable" class="random">
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>First</th>
     <th>Last</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id ="mybody">
     <tr>
           <td>James</td>
           <td>Smith</td>

  </tr>
   <tr>
           <td>Kyle</td>
           <td>Thompson</td>

  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I also have a function which replaces the rows in the table

```
 function addRow(item, i, tdcount) {
        document.getElementById("mybody").innerHTML = //replace rows
    }
```

The sort only works if I don't click the button to replace rows. As soon as I replace rows, the sort stops working. Is there a way to sort a table after it has been altered?

EDIT:
BTW, the table data is generated by an AJAX call to a different server which queries a database and returns a JSON object which I fill into the table

Comment: *"open source javascript table sorting function"* <- are we supposed to guess which one it is ?

Comment: http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/

Comment: BTW, the table data is generated by an AJAX call to a different server which queries a database and returns a JSON object which I fill into the table

Comment: Does the table structure changes before an after you edit an entry?

Comment: @RicardoNuñez Nope, I only change the contents of the entries within the table. The number of rows could change though.

Comment: I don't know the library, but does it loads the data on page load? You may want to add if the data changes, call the function again. I'll try to replicate your table and see if that's the issue.

Comment: @RicardoNuñez I think that might be the issue because before I was using server sided codebehind c# code to replace the rows in the table and the sort was working perfectly. However, I had to change to AJAX to get my row data so I had to switch to javascript (client-sided) to alter the table rows and I've had this issue since then.

Comment: Getting closer.. I added the call to the sorting function at the end of my addrow function, like so:             $("#myTable").tablesorter();
Now it sorts each column if I click it, but only the first time. I have to click a diff column first if I want to sort the original column again.

Comment: I fixed the problem, your original suggestion was correct.

Comment: Great. I'm glad it worked. I didn't make the comment as an answer because I was not familiar with the library.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you to use such sorting library. It uses global javascript variables and doesn't provide an API to acomplish what you want. You should use instead a library like listjs, sorttable or tablesort.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to simply add a call to the function after the table is altered:

```
function addRow(item, i, tdcount) {
    document.getElementById("mybody").innerHTML = //replace rows
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myTable").tablesorter();
        }
}
```